# Eliminar sms de la bandeja de mensajes recibidos

Tags: android, android-studio, sms

Buenas a todos,

Estoy realizando una app en **Android Studio** que intercambia SMS, pero me gustaría que al recibirlo lea el mensaje y automaticamente lo borre e la bandeja de sms recibidos.

Utilizo el siguiente código pero no me funciona:

```
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content:
//sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
do {
int indexBody = cur.getColumnIndex("body");
int indexId = cur.getColumnIndex("_id");
if (mensaje.equals(cur.getString(indexBody))) {
String uri = "content://sms/inbox" + cur.getInt(indexId); 
                         context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri), null, null);
                    }
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
```

La variable mensaje la leo correctamente antes.

Además, tengo todos los permisos en el manifest y aceptados en el movil.

Sabeís que puedo estar haciendo mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 4.4 Kitkat introdujo cambios en el manejo de SMS donde ahora solo la aplicación de SMS predeterminada tiene acceso de escritura a la base de datos de SMS; todas las otras aplicaciones fallan silenciosamente cuando intentan escribir.

Yo utilice este código hace poco para resolver algo parecido, claro esta que la app debe seleccionarse como aplicacion predeterminada de SMS en el dispositivo siempre que este tenga android 4.4 o superior.

```
Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null, null,null);
    try {
          while (c.moveToNext()) {
             int Id = c.getInt(0);
             String pid = c.getString(0);
            // String uri = "content://sms/conversations/" + threadId;
             String strUriAll = "content://sms/" + pid;//SMS_ALL
             Log.d("URI is ", strUriAll);
             getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(strUriAll), null, null);
          //   getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(strUriAll), null, null);
          }

        }catch(Exception e){
             Log.e(this.toString(),"Error deleting sms",e);
        }finally {
          c.close();
        }
```

Comment: No he intentado realizar la eliminación que necesita el OP , pero como comentas posiblemente en las últimas API´s esto ya no esta permitido por seguridad.